# creating unique session id ServletRequestAttributes

Tags: java

Issue with creating unique session id when request comes from same machine at same time

I am trying to create a unique session id as below :

```
HttpSession session = servletRequest.getServletRequest().getSession();
sessionId = session.getId();
String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
          .getRequest()
          .getRemoteAddr();
sessionId = sessionId.concat("_" + ipAddr + "_" + System.nanoTime() + "");
```

But here if a user tries to connect to multiple session at same time using same machine, then the session id does not remain unique, Can someone pls tell me how do I handle this case where IP and nanotime is same but I still want a unique session ID.

Comment: Use a [`UUID`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

Comment: UUID is the Best Chioce,Concat the same with IpAddress..

Comment: @TestName Why should the IP address be part of the session ID

Comment: Is this correct :
String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      //get client IP address
      String ipAddr = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
          .getRequest()
          .getRemoteAddr();
      String sessionId =(uniqueID + "_" + ipAddr );

Comment: @TestName: Would it run efficiently in a multi threaded environment to create unique ID where requests come in parallel threads from same user . Can you give me idea to test it / to write a testcase to verify the same

Comment: It will work efficiently,if multiple request coming frm the same user. you need to validate the UniquID+ip with exiting (i.e where you have stored your Uniqueid may be in session or cookies or db).

Comment: BTw..Once the user is logged in you will create the uuid and send it to client.r u sending back the response each and every time along with UUID?

Comment: @TestName : Yes, every time a session id is created using UUID+IP, I log it in log file, as well as send to client, because based on that session, some features/services are provided. session ID needs to be  maintained as we track data of every session based on it.